# How to save & load TFrame contents?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tframe, tform

I use the following code to save & load my Form:

```
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override; 
  procedure BeforeDestruction; override; 

var
  PreservePath: String;

constructor TMyForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin   
  PreservePath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) +
    'Preserve';
  if not DirectoryExists(PreservePath) then
    CreateDir(PreservePath);
    PreservePath := PreservePath + '\';
  if FileExists(PreservePath + ClassName + '.sav') then
  begin
    CreateNew(AOwner, 0);
    with TFileStream.Create(PreservePath + ClassName + '.sav',
                            fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite) do
    try
      ReadComponent(Self);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.BeforeDestruction;
begin
 inherited;
    with TFileStream.Create(PreservePath + ClassName + '.sav',
                            fmCreate) do
  try
    WriteComponent(self);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

it works fine for the Form but when trying to do the same with `TFrame` it's not working as it doesn't have the `CreateNew` procedure. How do I save & load this Frame? Especially if it contains dynamically created controls.

Windows 7, Delphi 7.

Comment: Your real problem here is that it's a mistake to use GUI controls to store your model data. You should design your GUI so that it present a view of the underlying data. And your underlying data is capable of persistence.

Comment: I just raised the issue because am looking for something similar to the previous code such as using `WriteComponent` and `ReadComponent` .and avoid using the `*.ini` files , or saving my data inside database ... the previous code saves the form with all of its components ,even the dynamic created ones.. but as i mentioned its not working in the case of `Tframe` using

Comment: ...which leads to the question: how do you store data in general? And why have you chosen to do it this way? What's the benefit over all other possibilities (INI, XML, DB, Registry...)? Saving every control's properties would only make sense if it's like a designer, where you indeed want to save each position/size/font...

Comment: Writing where the application exe file is is a bad idea. A good program is installed somewhere under *Program Files* (whatever it is) and there is no write permission by default. And granting write permission there is also a bad idea. Use a folder somewhere in the *AppData* branch for specific user data or in *Program Data* for all users data.

Comment: One more note: You should decouple data and GUI. Create one or more classes (Or in general a *data structure*) to handle your data, including persistence and create a GUI to input and show the data.

Comment: Thank you for the advice .. I will try to save my data is this way ..

Answer (score 0):

You can override Create / Destroy procedure of a Frame :

```
   type MyFrame = class(TFrame)
    ...
   public
       { Déclarations publiques }
       constructor create(AOwner: TComponent);override;
       destructor destroy;override;
```